# How to require webpack generate js file with requirejs?I use vue-cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, requirejs, vue.js

I make my project by vue-cli.

```
vue init webpack vue-demo
cd vue-demo
npm install 
npm run dev
```

Now I want to devolop some components. And i want to use them in requirejs.
webpack config

```
entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? config.build.assetsPublicPath : config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    library:'senyint'
  }
```

Q1:It generate three files. app.js manifest.js vendor.js
The demo has a Hello.vue . I want to require the js file by what webpack generate.
But I require them,it's undefiend . Why? What's the wrong?
Where I should export ? 
Now I export in main.js like this.

```
import Hello from 'components/Hello'
   module.exports = {
Hello
}
```

Q2:I dont want to package without vue.
So i configure this

```
externals: {
    vue: 'vue'
}
```

If i do this, when npm run dev show error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined"
It cause cant find Vue.
If i configure externals vue  how to make it run?

Answer (score 0):

Q1:
Open the javascript file app.js i found

```
define("senyint", ["vue"], factory);
```

at this line. The 'senyint' is a package name,webpack generate the js,but it doesnt work.
I modify the code like this

```
define(["vue"], factory);
```

Require it and it works. But I dont know why.... I just can resolve this problem;
main.js export .vue components

```
import Hello from 'components/Hello.vue'

export const scom = {
  Hello 
}
```

requirejs config

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'js/common',
  paths: {
    module: '../modules'
  },
  shim: {
    app: {
      deps:['vue','manifest','vendor']
    }
  }
})

requirejs(['module/demo', 'app'], function (demojs, app) {
  debugger
  console.log(app)
})
```

Q2:
I builded my project with vue-cli webpack template. (not webpack-simple)
In build directory has 'webpack.base.conf.js' and  'webpack.prod.conf.js'
Modify webpack.prod.conf.js  add

```
externals: {
    vue: {
      root: 'Vue',
      commonjs: 'vue',
      commonjs2: 'vue',
      amd: 'vue'
    }
  },
```

and dont add the code in 'webpack.base.conf.js' .Then npm run build it will package without vue.js .Npm run dev use webpack.base.conf.js ,it will run with vue